# Voice echoing in audacity?

Tags: echo

How do I do the following effect. In this video :

At 1 minute exactly, there is a voice echo when the kid is being bullied. How did they do those echos. How could I do this in audacity or sony vegas.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with Audacity's 'Echo' effect. You can set the Time delay to a small number (0.1 for example) and a smallish time decay factor (0.4?) to get the effect of 'being trapped in a large empty room'. But what it sounds like here is that they've kept the original as is and then used an altered copy of the same soundtrack with maybe half of a second delay.

You will need to play with parameters to achieve what you want, but it can be done!

Edit: Actually listening to it again, maybe they have used a larger decay factor with a larger delay, since you can hear the same echo multiple times... or maybe even applied a small echo on the top of the already existing echo.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this too in Vegas. Engage the audio effect button the audio clip portion, choose reverb in the menu "add", once you get the pop up on this effect choose "Cathedral" that out be enough, if not, tweak the controls in the pop up.